# Finding first non-alpha character

Tags: sql, instr

I need to look at a string, and find the first non-alphanumeric character in it, and truncate everything from that non-alphabetic character until the end of the string.

I know `REGEXP_INSTR` probably is involved, but cannot figure it out.

Can anyone offer some help?

Comment: Please post the database you are using, your code attempts and indicate where you are stuck.

Comment: [Why Should I Tag My RDBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms/)

Answer (score 0):

You can write regex for that.

```
select regexp_replace(column_name, '[a-zA-Z0-9].*', '')
from mytable;
```

This will replace `$$6th$%` into `$$`.

Comment: I'm not looking to replace, but find the first position of the first non-alpha character.   So, "AB-CD123" would result in 3.......